# what's wrong in this code mdx?

Tags: ssas, mdx

I wonder what's wrong in this code?

```
with 
member [CA Espagne] As
((select        [Measures].[CA], [[Site].[Pays - Site].[Pays].&[ES]))
select      {[Measures].[CA], [CA Espagne]} on 0, 
            [Temps].[Année - Mois - Jour].[Année].&[20100101].children on 1
from        [DistrisysOLAP_Global];
```

Answer (score 2):

Better to tell us the error you're getting... but I guess you should simply define your calculated member as :

```
with member [CA Espagne] As ( [Measures].[CA], [[Site].[Pays - Site].[Pays].&[ES] )
```

then the remaining of the statement looks ok (remove the trailing ; ). Otherwise, here is a [page](http://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/mdx_tutorial/calculated_members.html) explaining the syntax of the calculated members.

Comment: +1 Your calculated member doesn't need a select in it. You declare your member and then write your select statement.

Comment: Yes, the pbm was the first select, it shouldn't be there. I confuse it  with the CTE. tnx